# Favorite graphical subsystem to program in

Tags: user-interface, graphics

Ok, this is an interesting question to ask because everyone has a say in it.

What is your favorite library to program in for GUI's and the language that you program it in.  Give a short reason why.  (ex. Gtk, Qt, Windows, etc..)  Just an FYI, this includes any scripting language that you program a GUI in Python, Perl etc...

Frankly I've always done Gtk in C, but I'm starting to warm up to Qt in C++ with the new KDE.  I've never been a big fan of Windows programming.

ChrisW. stated that I did not give a reason for Gtk/Qt so here goes.  I started with Gtk because when I started programming GUI's I was working in Linux and there was more Gtk information available.  Started utilizing Qt when I started working more in KDE but really the move to Qt was based on trying to move to C++ and learn more languages.  I've never been a fan of basic Windows programming, but I do enjoy a little DirectX now and then :P

Comment: You said to "give a short reason why", but you didn't yourself give any reason for *your* preference.

Comment: @Chris, ouch... good move. Edit is coming.

Comment: this should be community wiki.

Comment: Why community wiki: is it so that people can more easily edit other people's posts? Or, because this is a poll where you might have people voting to say "yeah me too" to some answers?

Comment: If you ask a question which has no one true answer then it should probably be a CW. Also, this could be considered a poll.

Comment: This was actually an interesting question to pose to everyone, and I'll close it out since it's pretty much done (i.e. no one else answering).  Interesting to see the different languages that people work in and the libraries that they use.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had the opportunity to work with both wxWindows and QT, while some time ago I wrote some small programs using FLTK and Gtk. My conclusion is that widget libraries tend to be very similar; each one has its strenghts and its quirks.

Instead of advocating a specific library, then, I would like to advocate the use of high level languages in GUI programming: the development cycle is way faster and GUI programs are rarely CPU bound, so the performance hit is rarely a problem.

If a GUI program has to perform some intense computations, just develop a core library in C or C++, but keep the interface in Python or whatever other interpreted language.

Answer (score 2):

People like to bash Swing for being old, slow and ugly, but it's just not true. Swing is *mature*, is faster than ever on Java SE 6/10, looks decent enough, and is tolerable to program. Above all, I've found Java + Swing to be the most trouble-free cross-platform combination. It also works remarkably seamlessly with Jython (Python on JVM).

SWT could also be an option, but so far I've been happy with Swing.

Answer (score 1):

I realise you're focusing on application GUIs but if you want a quick, powerful and fun way to visualize anything on your computer, you can't go past [Processing](http://www.processing.org)

From the site:

> Processing is an open source
>   programming language and environment
>   for people who want to program images,
>   animation, and interactions. It is
>   used by students, artists, designers,
>   researchers, and hobbyists for
>   learning, prototyping, and production.
>   It is created to teach fundamentals of
>   computer programming within a visual
>   context and to serve as a software
>   sketchbook and professional production
>   tool. Processing is an alternative to
>   proprietary software tools in the same
>   domain.

Answer (score 1):

WPF in particular, and XAML in all its reincarnations (WPF, Silverlight, Moonlight).

C# on top of .Net 3.5/Mono: $0
Visual Studio Express/MonoDevelop: $0
Being able to tell the designer "make my program pretty" and continue coding features: priceless.

Answer (score 0):

I liked writing to video memory under DOS: for an animated game (i.e. an *Asteroids* clone), that was as fast (performant) as I knew how to do it (certainly faster that using the BIOS API).

Answer (score 0):

This is really a somewhat subjective question, so there is no best or correct answer to it.  The following is based on my (limited) experience:

I personally like **[wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)** with **[PLT Scheme](http://www.plt-scheme.org/)** for writing simple but flexible GUIs.  There are much more advanced toolkits, but I usually do not need their features.  wxWidgets is flexible and the Scheme interface follows Scheme traditions of being powerful with a relatively simple structure.  I like the fact that wxWidgets is portable, and yet tries not to actually draw its own widgets, but can use native or common toolkits of the environment it is used under.  It is written in C++ but I never used its C++ interface.

That is not to say that in my opinion Scheme will generally be the optimal language to write your application in.  In fact there are many kinds of applications I would not write in Scheme, even though I like the language.  But regarding the GUI programming part, that is my favourite because of its straight-forwardness, and the way that a functional language like Scheme goes well with declarative-style GUI programming.

Of course you will not have the same level of control when using that as when having your program involved in every stage of the window construction and input reaction, by using an event loop (such as with Win32API or Xt/Intrinsics).  But that is not always convenient and often unnecessary, and seems to become decreasingly common.

---

*Note:* The **wxWindows** toolkit was renamed **wxWidgets**, but my installation of a rather recent version of PLT Scheme still comes with the older wxWindows.  I am not sure whether there is an updated package of wxWidgets available or if it is going to be included in a future version of PLT Scheme.

Comment: Indeed, the question is completely subjective; but this is more of a interesting question to see what people use for a language and to give new programmers an idea of the languages available.

Answer (score 0):

Qt4 without question for me.  Now that it has an LGPL license it makes sense for all kinds of applications that previously weren't possible.  Additionally, it changes C++ in ways that dramatically improve the experience of using the language.  (Things like a foreach and forever loop, atomic operations on integers, and memory management)

Answer (score 0):

Gtk and  is the primary window-drawing graphical subsystem I have experience working with (and is therefore my favorite XD).

As far as general graphics subsystems go, however, OpenGL (typically in combination with GLUT) has been an easy and productive ride for me. Regrettably I have little DirectX experience to compare to, though :S

Answer (score 0):

For writing souped-up versions of standard Windows components, I loved Borland's VCL, and am very pleased with .NET.